# Add domain-specific entities to spaCy or Stanford NLP training set

Tags: stanford-nlp, spacy

We would like to add some custom entities to the training set of either Stanford NLP or spaCy, before re-training the model. We are willing to label our custom entities, but we would like to add these to the existing training set, so as to not spend too much time labeling.

We assume that the NLP model was trained on a large labeled data set, which includes labels for words that are labeled "O" ("other", i.e. nothing of interest) as well as words that are labeled "DATE", "PERSON", "ORGANIZATION", etc. We have a custom set of ORGANIZATION words, but we would like to add these to all the other labeled data, before re-training the model.

Is this possible? How can we do this? Do we have to get the labeled dataset that the models were trained on, so we can add our own data? If so, how can we do that?

We have built prototypes using both Stanford NLP and spaCy, so an answer for either one works for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For spaCy, you should just be able to call `nlp.update()`. This will make a weight update against the current weights, allowing you to resume training. If you want to make many updates, you might want to parse some text with the original model and mix that through your training, to avoid the "catastrophic forgetting" problem.

Comment: Found this link, which describes a process for achieving what we want: https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [entity tagger tool](https://helkaroui.github.io/projects/entity_tagger.html) by helkaroui to create your own training set.

[image: Entity Tagger]